# Python MYSql.connector will not insert data

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, bioinformatics

I am trying to insert some data into a a database I am making and it will not insert. I literally have used the same insert method on other code and it still seems to work, however this one refuses to. Help!

```
from Bio import Entrez
from sys import exit
Entrez.email = "A.N.Other@example.com"     # Always tell NCBI who you are
sranumber = raw_input("Input SRA number here")
sranumber2= raw_input("re-type SRA number here")
while True:
    if sranumber != sranumber2:
         print "SRA numbers do not match"
         sranumber2 = raw_input("Please re-type sra number to match intitial sra number")
         continue   
    else:
        break
print "SRA ID:" + sranumber
#answer = raw_input("Are you sure this is the sra number you wish to use? Type Y/N")
while True:
    answer = raw_input("Are you sure this is the sra number you wish to use? Type Y/N")
    if answer == "Y":
        print "Let's do it!"
        break
    elif answer == "y":
        print "Let's do it!"
        break
    elif answer == "yes":
        print "Let's do it!"
        break
    elif answer == "YES":
        print "Let's do it!"
        break
    elif answer == "N":
        exit()
    else:
        print "Not a valid answer"
search = Entrez.esearch(term = sranumber, db = "SRA", retmode = "xml")
record = Entrez.read(search, validate = False)
newstuff = record
#print newstuff
for j in record:
    if j == "WarningList":
        newstuff = record['WarningList']
#print newstuff
poop = newstuff
for item in poop:
    if item == "OutputMessage":
        poop = poop['OutputMessage']
#print poop
crap = ['Wrong UID' + " " + sranumber]
cool =  "'"+crap[0]+"'"
#print cool
continuity = ''
for j in poop:
    if j  == 'No items found.' or j == cool:
        print "[-] This is not a valid SRA identity"
        continuity = 'done'
if continuity == 'done':
    exit()
print "[+] This is a valid SRA identity"
print "SRA ID:" + sranumber


condition = raw_input("Type in the condition of your ngs_data here")
condition2 = raw_input("re-type the condition of your ngs_data here")
print condition
while True:
    if condition != condition2:
        print "Conditions do not match!"
        condition2 = raw_input("Please retype condition here to match first condition")
    else:
        break
print "just dropped in to check on what condition my condition was in"
stuff = []
stuff.append(sranumber)
stuff.append(condition)
stuff2 = '+'.join(stuff)
print stuff2
stuff3 = stuff2.split('+')
print stuff3
experiment = [tuple(stuff3)]
print experiment
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config

def insert_books(experiment):
    query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO organisms(sra#, condition) " \
                "VALUES(%s,%s)"

    try:
        db_config = read_db_config()
        conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.executemany(query, experiment)

        conn.commit()
    except Error as e:
        print('Error:', e)

    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

def main():

    insert_books(experiment)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What if you would use `INSERT INTO` instead of `INSERT IGNORE INTO`?

Comment: ('Error:', ProgrammingError()) This is the only error im getting. and the insert into has the same problem as the insert ignore. also there are no foreign keys in this table but one attribute is referenced as a foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just doing it this way and it finally worked. I am unsure why it did not work before but I believe that it had something to do with the formatting of how i typed in the columns.

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='*****',database = 'new')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
addstuff= ("INSERT IGNORE INTO experiment (`sra`, `condition`) VALUES(%s,%s)")
cursor.execute(addstuff,stuff3)
cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```